# Unable to get function in a page working only in live server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Link to mysite: http://210.48.154.18/~econtrax/ezy/index.php

I'm trying to login and register. But both functions failed. Meaning can access the pages related but the functions written in them don't pass through.

I checked the console, the error caught my attention was:

```
XMLHttpRequest.n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send.b
```

What does this indicate and how to fix?I referred the same type of question but I don't find such a typo error in my script.

> [jquery / ajax form - serverside php but get Cross domain warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802180/jquery-ajax-form-serverside-php-but-get-cross-domain-warning)

Full error thrown:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at n.parseJSON (http://210.48.154.18/~econtrax/ezy/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:5497)
>       at ub (http://210.48.154.18/~econtrax/ezy/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:7521)
>       at x (http://210.48.154.18/~econtrax/ezy/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:10935)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send.b (http://210.48.154.18/~econtrax/ezy/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:14765)

Comment: did you check for violation of  'same origin policy' ? If this happens to AJAX, try to set `dataType: 'jsonp'`

Comment: When I try to enter a user name and password and press the button below it, I see a POST ajax request send, and a 200 response, but the response is set to text/html and is empty.  So, presumably when your code tries to parse the response as JSON, you get an error.  This looks like a server-side issue to me.  Again, no response is received when I try to register.